# How to mark missing class items in jsoup?

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I am trying to parse some data from a html file like this: one block of the file is:

```
<span class="xxxxlarge green mt5px fl"><img src="http://static.exportersindia.com/ei_images/phone_icon.png" class="vam" alt="">+86-13924109788</span>
```

when I use:

```
Elements phoneNo = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "xxxxlarge green mt5px fl");
```

That works fine.

But my query is: when

```
<span class="xxxxlarge green mt5px fl"><img src="http://static.exportersindia.com/ei_images/phone_icon.png" class="vam" alt="">+86-13924109788</span>
```

part is missing in some part of the file, how can I recognise that this span class is missing in this block of the file?

N.B: There are several blocks of the span class tag containing phone number.
Please suggest something.

Comment: "how can I recognise that this span class is missing" first try to explain what lets *you* realize it is missing.

Comment: @Pshemo,There are several blocks of a webpage containing a specific product of different companies and every block contains some basic info like product-name, web-url, address, contact info. But  each of them genuinely does not contain contact info. So I need to recognise which company does not provide contact info and who does provide.

Comment: Check for each of your blocks if the query's result is null or not.